# Problem retrieving from map of lists

Tags: c++, std

In my program, I have a map with string keys and list (of a user-defined class) values, defined like so:

```
std::map<const char*, std::list<Show>> _shows;
```

I have a function that adds to a specific list, like so:

```
void Add(Show s, const char* index) {
list<Show> lshow = _shows[index];
lshow.push_back(s); }
```

However, every time the function is called with the same index, rather than returning the same list, I get an empty list.

What am I doing wrong?

ETA: I see the number of values in the dictionary increases after each time I call the function. Could this be [] operator related?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key in your map is the pointer value, not its contents. Therefore weird behavior. Change the map so that its key be `std::string`. Also, you modify the copy of your stored list. To avoid this, use a reference

```
list<Show>& ls = map[index]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a reference:

```
list<Show>& lshow = _shows[index];
```

Since otherwise you're creating a temporary copy and adding to it.

You're seeing the number of items in the map increase because you're searching for a different *pointer* each time, even if it points to the same value. Doing this adds an empty value when it fails if you're using `operator[]`.

You need to compare the actual values (by defining a comparator that you pass to the map constructor), or use `std::string`s as keys.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a const char * as a std::map key. The map's being sorted by the pointer addresses, not the pointed-to strings. To get the behaviour you want, use:

```
std::map<std::string,std::list<Show> >
```

Comment: And also make sure you're editing the list stored in the map, not a copy of it, as everyone else is saying :)

Answer (score 0):

When you write `list<Show> lshow = _shows[index]` you are actually making a copy of the list found in your map. What you want is a reference on this list : `list<Show> &lshow = _shows[index]`.

Answer (score 0):

`lshow` is a copy of `_shows[index]`. Try `_shows[index].push_back(s)`, or else take `_shows[index]` as a *reference*:

```
std::list<Show> &lshow = _shows[index];
lshow.push_back(s);
```

Also consider renaming `_shows` because names starting with an underscore are generally reserved for the standard library.